# Constant time "is bool array all 0's?"

Tags: c++

I have a boolean array:

```
bool * arr = new bool[n];
```

I want to figure out in constant time if there are any 1's in this array; can this be done?
I know bitset has a none() method which does the same thing, but this array needs to be dynamically sized, and boost's dynamic_bitset isn't really an option.

*Edited for clarity*

Comment: Since there isn't any variable in there you can just iterate over the array: it will take constant time. If you start changing the number of elements you won't get a constant time operation to see if there is any `1` in there unless you modify the access to the data structure to record how many values are currently set.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't even think that using a bitset and AND'ing every element would be faster (but a lot more space efficient).

Comment: If you control when the arr is set, you can keep a counter of the number of values set, and compare with that counter.

Comment: Since you have the adress(arr) and size(100000), couldn't you access the memory, treat it like integer(s) and check if it's bigger than 0?

Comment: What is the largest the array can be?

Comment: I just changed it from 100000 to n...that was badly worded. As Oli Charlesworth said below, "something has to iterate over those bits", even if it's something low level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No.  You have to examine half the elements on average, and that takes O(n) time.

**Long answer:** Yes.  If you're prepared to add some extra O(1) complexity to your write operations.  Just keep track of every 0->1 and 1->0 with an up/down counter.

---

*Note: I'm assuming that in the general case you have `bool *arr = new bool[n];`.  For a constant-sized array, then yes of course the query will be constant time!*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I now have some followup questions.  1) Is bitset::none() constant? and 2) since the bits are all lined up in memory, is there no way to manipulate this to get what I want?

Comment: Why would write operations take O(N)?  If you keep a count of number of 1s in the array then writing a value to the array only needs to update the count.

Comment: You can maintain the number of currently set `true` values with O(1), i.e. you don't need a funny complexity on write operations: count up if the member changes from `false` to `true`, count down if the member changes from `true` to `false`. Is there any bit set: `0 < count`.

Comment: @codersarepeople: (1) I'm not sure.  (2) No.  Something still needs to iterate over all the bits in turn.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, but you can easily maintain a count of 1s:

- increment it whenever 0 turns into 1
- and decrement it when 1 turns into 0.

Once you have done that, comparing the count to 0 is a constant-time operation.

So, essentially, you trade slightly degraded write performance in exchange to answering "are there any 1s left" faster. Whether this is the right tradeoff, only you can know...

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to control access to the array, you could write a wrapper that maintains a count of the number of 1's in the array as items are updated.